# kadmin does not use kinit for authentication?

Tags: kerberos

First, I run `kinit {principal} -k -t {keytabfile}` with keytab file.

Second, I run `klist` to check whether there exists TGT.

All seems work fine, but when I run `kadmin -p {principal}`, keytab or password still needed.

Does that means kadmin does not use kinit for authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the default policy for the kadmin service principal (for obvious security) to only accept tickets obtained directly for that service.  You can change that if you want but not recommended.

If you check in the kdc logs you'll notice

`Jun 18 01:17:27 aron krb5kdc[21377](info): TGS_REQ (4 etypes {18 17 16 23}) 192.168.1.56: TGT BASED NOT ALLOWED: authtime 0,  root/DOMAIN.NET for kadmin/@DOMAIN.NET, KDC policy rejects request`

Here is a reference to the docs on this default policy

https://github.com/krb5/krb5/blob/50a3c3cbeab32577fba2b21deb72a64015c48ec7/doc/kadm5/api-funcspec.tex#L775

> Two Kerberos principals exist for use in communicating with the Admin
>   system: kadmin/admin and kadmin/changepw.  Both principals
>   have the KRB5_KDB_DISALLOW_TGT_BASED bit set in their attributes so
>   that service tickets for them can only be acquired via a
>   password-based (AS_REQ) request.  Additionally, kadmin/changepw
>   has the KRB5_KDB_PWCHANGE_SERVICE bit set so that a principal with an
>   expired password can still obtain a service ticket for it.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Could you give some reference?

Comment: from the docs [Database Administration](https://github.com/krb5/krb5/blob/master/doc/admin/database.rst)

If the credentials cache contains a ticket for either service principal and the -c ccache option is specified, that ticket is used to authenticate to KADM5. Otherwise, the -p and -k options are used to specify the client Kerberos principal name used to authenticate. Once kadmin has determined the principal name, it requests a kadmin/admin Kerberos service ticket from the KDC, and uses that service ticket to authenticate to KADM5.

Comment: This is it actually https://github.com/krb5/krb5/blob/50a3c3cbeab32577fba2b21deb72a64015c48ec7/doc/kadm5/api-funcspec.tex#L775